# How to change status Bar Color in Jetpack Compose + Material 3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-statusbar

I'm following the theming tutorial from [developer.google](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-superheroes?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-3-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-superheroes#4). I'm trying to migrate the app to Mat. 3 and modify the status bar's color to match with the background color.

- After adding `android:statusBarColor` and `android:windowLightStatusBar`, nothing changes.
- I noticed that at the very first moments the app loading, status bar is really as my expected, but a moment later it becomes wrong.

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i43cL.png

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMwaP.png

What I've tried:

```
// res/values/themes.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Superheroes" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/background_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
// res/values-night/themes.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Superheroes" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/background_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Look at your AppTheme composable, if you created your app from android studio template, status bar color is changed there.

Comment: Have you applied the theme to the activity in the mnifest?

Comment: Use accompanist

Comment: @JanBína that helps! I forgot that.

Comment: @zjmo yes I have applied it but I can see xml has been overrided by Compose in runtime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way to change it without adding a dependency is at `ui.theme/Theme.kt` as @2801938 has mentioned:

```
@Composable
fun YourAppTheme(darkTheme...) {
    ...
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[DEPRECATED]

In Jetpack Compose the easiest is to use the Accompanist System UI Controller.

Add this to your dependencies : `implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.27.0"`

Then, in your MainActivity:

```
setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

                    SideEffect {
                        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
                            color = Color(0xff655D8A),
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[Source and details here.](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm looking for the way to do it without adding a dependency. In the comment section I actually found that!

Comment: this library is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

The compose samples project [Jetchat](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetchat) does this through xml themes.

Be sure to cover all android versions as they do in the various `themes.xml` files in the same way they do or you'll end up with some weird behaviour on specific versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primaryContainer.toArgb()
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
    }
}
```

Change the `primaryConatiner` color in Color.kt file and then change it also according to Light and Dark theme like this

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
primaryContainer = Color.Black,
onPrimaryContainer = Color.White
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
primaryContainer = RoyalBlue,
onPrimaryContainer = Color.White
)
```

In Color.kt file

```
val RoyalBlue = Color(0xFF246EE9)
```